# Kunstmaan Bundle admin login incorrectly redirects to homepage after system update, does not log in user

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have the Kunstmaan CMS bundles (Symfony 2.4 version) installed on a project that had been working fine until a system update a couple days ago; now, when attempting to log into the admin panel (/en/admin; /en/login) I get redirected to the homepage as an anonymous user, unless I explicitly check the "Remember Me" option in the login form.

This same issue arose simultaneously across all projects using these bundles, including ones that hadn't been modified in weeks.

The admin user last_login *is* being modified in the database, so it is getting as far as successfully validating the login credentials, but the user session is not being updated.

I'm running CentOS 6.5 on a VM, and the following packages are all the ones that were updated that seem to have anything to do with the web hosting environment:

```
httpd 2.2.15-31.el6.centos.x86_64
nodejs 0.10.29-1.el6.x86_64
nodejs-devel 0.10.29-1.el6.x86_64
nodejs-packaging 7-1.el6.noarch
php54w-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64
php54w-cli-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                      
php54w-common-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                   
php54w-gd-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                       
php54w-intl-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                     
php54w-mbstring-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                 
php54w-mysql-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                    
php54w-pdo-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                      
php54w-process-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64                  
php54w-tidy-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64            
php54w-xml-5.4.30-1.w6.x86_64
```

The problem happens in all browsers.

I've been pulling my hair out over this for hours, so if anyone has any thoughts it would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: did you look at what those updates changed?

Comment: I have, but I'm not a native linux user, so a lot of those changelogs are getting into an area that's just completely over my head.  From what I was able to decipher, I didn't see anything directly related to session handling, but...


Honestly, I may be completely out to lunch on this having anything to do with the system update at all, though I don't know why else multiple projects would all be affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.

My project was saving the sessions to %kernel.cache_dir%/sessions.  Because I'm hosting the project in a VM, but editing the files from my workstation proper, the permission structure in my projects dir is a bit odd; Apache is running as apache:apache while the ownership on sessions dir was 1000:1000, and the session files within are rw------- 1000:1000. Apache can't write to these files.

This had been working fine previously, so in my last system update something apparently either changed the permission structure somewhere, or started stricter enforcing of a messed up system that had no business working in the first place.

Rather than muck around with the permissions in that dir, I just changed the symfony framework config:

```
framework:
    session:
        save_path:          /tmp/myprojectname
```

Problem solved, and I can log in normally.

Comment: it didn't help actually

Answer (score 0):

You should fix your `/path/to/app` 
E.g. `http://127.0.0.1:8888/web/app_dev.php/en/admin/login`

If you are still having issues: I have recorded my notes [here](https://github.com/vvallabb/KunstmaanAnsibleSandbox/blob/master/README.md).